# How can I improve my on hold question?

Tags: discussion

My [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/375318/software-development-methods-or-practices-before-sql-server-max-worker-threads-i) was put on-hold due to off-topic.

I had updated my question since then.

How else can I improve my question?

Answer (score 2):

This site is about **software engineering**. Design-level questions are generally welcome.

But your question is not about software engineering. When I read (and voted to close) your question, it seemed to be more about **database administration**. Asking us to debug your database would be off topic. It would also be impossible with the sparse information in your question.

You have made it clear in your question that you want to know what you can do *as a developer*, but this doesn't magically make the question on topic. It seems like you are trying to solve a database-related problem while ignoring that database. The answer you already got sums up all the advice possible with that information: “Make sure your queries are fast.”

While I don't think this particular question can be made on topic, you might be able to ask better questions in the future:

- Define a clear problem and start doing your own analysis of this problem. Most of the time the response to “X is slow” is not “oh yeah, just tweak this secret configuration option”, but “what do we know? There are a gazillion of things that could be wrong”. E.g. you could try to measure your queries to see if there are a few particular slow queries. You could consider whether the server hardware is proportional to its workload.

  For example, your analysis could significantly clarify the question as being about using some ORM library, about the design of your database schema, about the particular configuration of your database server, or about Windows process priorities.
- Next, identify which [Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773) (if any) would be applicable for the clarified question. Read the `/help/on-topic` page to see whether the site might be a fit. Search for similar questions. In this case, possible sites might be:

  - Stack Overflow, for when you have a code-level question, e.g. using a particular database interface library or when trying to optimize an expensive query.
  - Software Engineering, for design-level questions or software engineering concepts.
  - Database Administrators, for DB configuration, stored procedures, and advanced SQL.
- When you ask the question, clearly describe the problem in a way that other people can understand. We don't work with the system and have no idea what it does. It may be helpful to indicate what kinds of workload this system handles. E.g. is this CRUD web app or an OLAP system?

  Value the time of potential answerers, so do write a couple of paragraphs with relevant information but don't write a lengthy description that spans many screens.

  Include the results of your analysis so far. Tell us what you already tried to solve the problem even if it didn't work. This prevents answers with stuff that you already know.
- In some cases, the Q&A format simply might not be a good fit for your problems. This works well when there's a clear question that has a “correct” answer. This does not work well for questions that require much back and forth in order to clarify the question first. For that reason, questions on Stack Overflow are expected to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it's not a valid question even after edit?

Answer (score -3):

I did answer your question before it was deleted. I hope it helped you, but you can see why its not particularly helpful to the general public.